# Is there a way to set height and wrap content at the same time in android?

Tags: java, android, button, height

I have a button, and I want it to have a minimum height of 50dp's but I also want it to get bigger and wrap if the text is too long, is this possible? Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

yes there is a [minHeight xml attribute.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3aminHeight)

```
android:minHeight="50dp"
```